# How can I tell which options PETSc was compiled with?

Tags: petsc

I'm working on a machine with a version of PETSc compiled by someone else. Is there a straightforward way to find out which options were used at compile time from the installation itself?  For example, is there a file that has all of the compile time options that is generated by `make`?

Comment: Try looking inside the Makefile and files which it includes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

- Check `$PETSC_ARCH/conf/reconfigure-$PETSC_ARCH.py` (where `$PETSC_ARCH` is expanded, i.e. for me that is 'arch-c')
- Depending on which information you want, you could use `make getlinklibs` or `make getincludedirs`
- Also, you could check `$PETSC_ARCH/include/petscconf.h` for all the standard `#ifdef`'s that PETSc was configured with

Comment: For lower level information, the file `$PETSC_ARCH/conf/petscvariables` has everything defined for `make` (there are some generated rules in `petscrules`), but Sean is right that looking in the reconfigure script is best.

Answer (score 1):

In the source directory, there is a log file to record every output of the screen including the commands has been input.